# Wheres the documentation for swfaddress-optimizer.js?

Tags: javascript, flash, actionscript, swfaddress

I am trying to make a full Flash site SEO'd and have come across a problem which it seems the swfaddress optimizer javascript can fix, but i can't find out how to configure it. Does anyone know of any documentation or examples to help me out.
Thanks
dai

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The swfaddress-optimizer.js does not need any documentation. This file simply needs to be included in your HTML. The documentation and configuration that is required for making your Flash site search engine friendly lies in creating a mod_rewrite rule on your Apache server and configuring an PHP script to handle the incoming URLs. Take a look at the SEO sample project provided in the SWFAddress distribution.

Comment: there are three variables for the optimizer, which i dont know how to process, some documentation on them would help me use them. there is no info on that or the php implementation.

Comment: Take a look at the SEO example on asual.com. The first variable 'flash' is equal to version number you're using. In the asual example its set to "8". The second variable 'swfaddress' should be set to "/" but it needs to be URL encoded so its set to %2f. The third variable 'base' is set to the folder path of your HTML page. In the asual example its set to /swfaddress/samples/seo. Again, notice the slashes are URL encoded.

Comment: Actually, I think you are wrong Matt... the second variable should not always be %2f, nor the base parameter works as expected... I too think swfaddress-optimizer needs documentation. I think it doesn't have one since one of its purposes is to fool search engines.

Answer (score 0):

There's the API reference here: http://www.asual.com/swfaddress/docs/
and lots of sample code http://www.asual.com/swfaddress/samples/.

Comment: hi Matti
i am aware of the swfaddress documentation, but i'm after swfaddress optimizer specific information.